# "Lvalue required" error

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code and when I compile it I get the "Lvalue required" error. Please point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  char r[5];
  int mark;
  cout<<"Please enter your goddamn marks";
  cin>>mark;
  r=mark>=35?"pass":"fail";
  cout<<"\n"<<r;
}
```

Comment: Try this: `const char* r=mark>=35?"pass":"fail";`

Comment: Don't use `void main()`. It isn't standard.

Comment: I'm forced to use. It's actually for school.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
r=mark>=35?"pass":"fail";
```

You cannot assign a string literal to a `char` array. You have several options:

- use `strcpy()` instead of assignment;
- change `r` to be of type `const char*`;
- change `r` to be of type `std::string`.

The last option is by far the best.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use them, as this is for school basis & this has not been taught to us, though I already know it. Any other Ideas ?

Comment: @Netizen110: What is it exactly that you're not allowed to do? I've given you three options.

Comment: Actually, the guy who teaches told us to write the exactly same code in the exam, so I thought I was wrong somewhere, but now I'm preety much sure that the teacher is wrong. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: If youre not allowed to use ` std::string`,  and be it just for "now", the teacher is not only wrong but also silly.

Comment: @Netizen110: To be brutally frank, if this code was given to you by a C++ instructor, I think it may be time to look into changing instructors.

Comment: I'm learning at school, so this subject is added with my syllabus, so I can't help it or change the school for just one subject. The code is to be written on paper & not on a PC, so no one actually cares, unless until the practicals come. btw, I'm actually a back-end web developer, just new into this client-side stuff.

Comment: @Netizen110: If your teacher told you to write *that exact line of code* then he simply isn't fit to be teaching C++ as he doesn't know what he's doing. There are no "other options", you simply cannot assign to an array after its declaration.

Comment: @Evgeni: I once had points deducted for using a loop before we were taught about loops... yeah.  I already knew how to program before starting my CS courses.   I dropped out, have been working as a systems engineer for 5 years now.  This sort of thing doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @EdS. Thats sad. Really. You get taught to mess around whith pointers and char arrays and other error-prone, time-consuming things and then they go: "Oh, and btw, theres something called STL. You  might wanna check it out..."